# Derivative of Tangent Vector Bases in Polar Coordinates

Tags: physics, vector-analysis

In physics using polar coordinates, I have seen $\frac{d e_r}{d \theta}=e_\theta$ and $\frac{d e_\theta}{d \theta}=-e_r$ where $e_r,e_\theta$ is the usual basis of the tangent space at point $(r,\theta)$ in the plane in polar coordinates.

See e.g. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec05.pdf.

In particular, the vectors $e_r$ and $e_\theta$ actually changes depending on where the point $(r,\theta)$ is. I am struggling to understand these equations mathematically.

First, I am most used to describing the tangent plane as something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$. But then e.g. $\frac{d\frac{\partial}{\partial r}}{d \theta}$ makes no sense to me. Is there any way to recover this point of view or is it too algebraic?

Now, geometrically if we consider $e_r, e_\theta$ to be just vectors then I can understand how to obtain these equations I think. They basically come from identifying all the tangent spaces as a single $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane in the obvious way so that we can actually compare vectors that belong in different tangent spaces. Then e.g. the first equation $\frac{d e_r}{d \theta}=e_\theta$ comes from looking at $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e_r^2-e_r^1}{h}$ where $e_r^1$ is that basis vector at $(r,\theta)$ and $e_r^2$ is that basis vector at $(r,\theta+h)$. I switched to cartesian coordinates to compute the limit then switched back to polar coords.

Is there any way to do this from the point of view of the differential operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$?

Comment: Your penultimate paragraph is correct: to calculate the derivatives of the canonical tangent basis vectors, you need an "affine connection," which allows you to compare tangent vectors at different points and gives a "covariant derivative." The equations in your first sentence are really giving you the Christoffel symbols for planar polar coordinates. In the general case of an arbitrary smooth manifold, the covariant derivative / affine connection are not part of the smooth structure: they must be specified *in addition to* the local coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a bit on my comment.

Suppose you work on an arbitrary smooth manifold with local coordinates $(x_1, x_2)$. These coordinates define a basis of each tangent space given by the operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$. For simplicity of the notation, call these operators $\mathbf{b}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{b}_{2}$, respectively. In an arbitrary smooth manifold, this is all that can be done: there is not enough structure to calculate the "second derivatives" $\frac{\partial\mathbf{b}_i}{\partial x_j}$.

The extra data that is needed is supplied by an affine connection or a covariant derivative (each determines the other). The covariant derivative is perhaps simplest to understand in terms of the [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) $\Gamma^k_{i,j}$, which specify the "second derivatives" of the standard basis vectors:

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{b}_i}{\partial x_j}=\sum_{k=1}^n\Gamma^k_{i,j}\mathbf{b}_k$$

The coefficients $\Gamma^k_{i,j}$ just tell how to express the partial derivative of $\mathbf{b}_i$ with respect to $x_j$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors $\mathbf{b}_k$.

[This page](http://www.physicspages.com/2013/12/22/christoffel-symbols-in-terms-of-the-metric-tensor/) works out the Christoffel symbols for planar polar coordinates.

Comment: Oh ok so in terms of the connection $\nabla$ my first equation $\frac{d e_r}{dθ}=e_θ$ is the same as $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$? Also, in the link you provided I noticed a $r$ factor that isn't present in the notes I linked. For example, it says $\frac{d e_r}{dθ}=\frac{1}{r}e_θ$. I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @Camilo: $e_i$ in the MIT notes is not the $e_i$ in the notes I linked to. In the MIT notes, $e_i$ is normalized to have unit length. In the notes I linked to, $e_i$ stands for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.

Answer (score 0):

Simple case the parameter is $\theta$
You have the equation of the vector for the parametric equation, velocity and acceleration, by taking derivatives using "derivatives of unit basis vectors", as if they where a product of two function.
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec r &= r(\theta) \hat e_r\\
\frac {d\vec r} {d\theta} &= \frac {dr} {d\theta}\hat e_r+r\hat e_\theta\\
\frac {d^2\vec r} {d\theta^2} &= \left(\frac {d^2 r} {d\theta^2}-r\right) \hat e_r +\frac {dr} {d\theta} \hat e_\theta
\end{aligned}$$
The tangent unit vector will always be the velocity over the speed.

Case two you can compose the angle as a function of $t$, and that make it a little bet more difficult but it have the same logic but with more chain rule.